# remove time from date and print only date in datetime format

Tags: c#

i have date stored in a string format as follows: "2014-03-12"
im passing this to a database which accepts the date as datetime.
im converting the string date to datetime format as follows:

```
DateTime StartDates = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
```

but the time gets appended along with the date as "2014-03-12 12:00:00:00"

can anyone tel me how to send only the date leaving out the time.
i want the final date to be still in datetime format only but with time part cut off

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime` is **irrespective of the format**. Formatting is only useful for presentation purpose. A `DateTime` object will have a `Date` part and `Time` part. When you try parsing your string `"2014-03-12"`, it doesn't have a `Time` part, so in the parsed object, Time is set to `00:00:00`.

If you just want to to display date then you can use `DateTime.ToShortDateString` method or use a custom format like:

```
string formattedDateString = StartDates.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against `DateTime.ToShortDateString`, but other than that this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Crono, `ToShortDateString` is useful when you want to show only `Date` part for any culture, like for US culture it would show `MM/dd/yyyy` and for British culture it will show `dd/MM/yyyy`. Could you please specify why it shouldn't be used. *(in OPs case it can't be used since OP is targeting a custom format for displaying)*

Comment: I'm so sorry, it seems my brain decided to completely ignore that obvious *If you just want to display date* right before. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with the date part, you may simply return the `Date` property of the `DateTime` conversion result:

```
DateTime StartDates = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date;
```

I should mention that using `Convert.ToDateTime` puts you at the mercy of the process current culture date format though, so you probably want to use the `ParseExact` or `ToString` method like the other answers suggests, with the appropriate format and culture instance.